# Bundle products with variable qty

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, bundled-product

I need to set bundle products that it will have variable qty. For making the final product customer needs 6 parts of Item A, 2 parts of Item B and 1 part of Item C. For example

```
Bundle product #a should contains at qty:
1 = 1 Item A + 1 Item B + 1 Item C
2 = 2 Item A + 1 Item B + 1 Item C
3 = 3 Item A + 1 Item B + 1 Item C
4 = 4 Item A + 2 Item B + 1 Item C
5 = 5 Item A + 2 Item B + 1 Item C
6 = 6 Item A + 2 Item B + 1 Item C
```

I wouldnt mind to put the qty of associated items for each qty of bundle.

EDIT: Customer should not have the option to choose how many of Item A, B and C. He should be able to choose how many products #a he wants only.

To better explain my need. This is calculator in Excel. What I need is to let customer choose only qty of column A which contains numbers of Items A, B, C.. in columns B, C, D.. I hope this is understandable. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y5z2j7bj5br5k4p/calculator.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: This needs a better real world example.  I know bundles inside and out and can't make out what you're asking here...

Comment: I've updated my question. I hope I did better job than before.

Comment: It would help more to give a real world example of how you want the bundle to look/work.  Are 1-6 your bundle options?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit confusing, because you say the customer needs a variable qty, but then you say that the "final product" will have specific quantities of the products.

Please explain how the customer flow will work, or elaborate on the issue your having setting up the bundle product.

Division Lab (Formerly Solvingmagento) has a great tutorial on the bundle product: 
http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/magento-bundle-product-type-part-1/